# Grease Pencil animation problem: old frame persists after making new keyframe (VİDEO)

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil

Why does the old keyframe not disappear even though I put in a new keyframe?

VİDEO: https://youtu.be/57Er6DBfQjk

Answer (score 0):

You have Onion skinning on. If you play the animation you will see that the strokes are gone. This feature is to help you see the frames before to animate